# I'd like to setup a bond0 interface using 2 eth devices in CentOS 7 in VirtualBox?

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox, vagrant, bonding

I would like to set up a CentOS 7.x VM inside of VirtualBox so I can experiment with bonding interfaces. How can I set up this VM so that it has the following interfaces:

- eth1 (private network - 192.168.56.101)
- eth2 (slave to bond0)
- eth3 (slave to bond0)
- bond0 (using LACP)

Using Vagrant to facilitate the setup would be helpful so it's easier to replicate.

**NOTE:** I'd like to do the setup manually, so please show an example where NetworkManager is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setting up Vagrant

To start you can use the following `Vagrantfile` to construct your VM:

```
$ cat Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.hostname="box-101"
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)", auto_config: false
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)", auto_config: false

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    yum install -y git vim socat tcpdump wget sysstat
    yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
  SHELL
end
```

**NOTE:** The NIC I'm using for my `public_network`'s is my Macbook's `bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)"` device. If you're doing this on anything else you'll need to change this to an appropriate NIC on your host system where Vagrant/VirtualBox is running.

The above file contains 3 NICs that will result when the VM is launched. To launch the VM and SSH into it:

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
```

#### Initial network setup

If we look at the resulting networking, we'll see the following:

```
$ ip a l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c0:42:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85127sec preferred_lft 85127sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec0:42d5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ce:88:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fece:8839/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::df68:9ee2:4b5:ad5f/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:59:b0:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And the corresponding routing:

```
$ ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.101 metric 102
```

#### Disable NetworkManager

For this VM we're going to disable NetworkManager, just so we can manually configure the bonding interface + slaves.

```
$ for i in NetworkManager-dispatcher NetworkManager NetworkManager-wait-online; do
    systemctl disable $i && systemctl stop $i
  done
```

Confirming that NM is now disabled:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files |grep NetworkManager
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service             disabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service            disabled
NetworkManager.service                        disabled
```

#### Setting up bonding interface

To start we're going to construct 3 files. 1 for the bond0 interface, and 1 for each of he 2 interfaces that we're going to use as the slaves (eth2 & eth3).

*ifcfg-bond0*

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
DEVICE=bond0
Type=Bond
NAME=bond0
BONDING_MASTER=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.232
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.2
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1"
```

**NOTE:** `mode=4` is (802.3ad) aka. LACP. `miimon=100` is 100ms check interval, and `lacp_rate=1` is fast TX from partner. You can see all the params that the bonding module accepts via this command `modinfo bonding`.

*eth2*

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
DEVICE=eth2
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPV6INIT=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

*eth3*

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth3
DEVICE=eth3
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPV6INIT=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

**NOTE:** In the above I'm statically assigning the bond0 interface the IP address 192.168.1.232 & the gateway 192.168.1.2. You'll want to change these to something appropriate for your situation.

#### Starting the interface

By far the easiest way to start the network is to restart the network service:

```
$ systemctl restart network
```

If we take a look at the interfaces and the routing:

```
$ ip a l
..
..
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.232/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed7:c2ec/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1003
169.254.0.0/16 dev bond0 scope link metric 1006
192.168.1.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.232
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.101
```

#### Bonding details

We can also take a look at the bonding interface's device for further details on the interfaces state:

```
$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 1
    Actor Key: 9
    Partner Key: 1
    Partner Mac Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec
    port key: 9
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 207
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 3

Slave Interface: eth3
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:59:b0:69
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: churned
Partner Churn State: churned
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 08:00:27:d7:c2:ec
    port key: 9
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 199
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 3
```

#### Verifying external connectivity

Below you can see the output of a ping to the bond0's IP address that I had running on another box in my network. As soon as we restarted the `network` service, we can see that it became accessible:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.232
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=7414 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=7415 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7416 ttl=64 time=886 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7417 ttl=64 time=3.58 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7418 ttl=64 time=3.52 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7419 ttl=64 time=3.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7420 ttl=64 time=3.15 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.232: icmp_seq=7421 ttl=64 time=3.50 ms
```

#### Rebooting tip

On CentOS 7.x there appears to be a bug/issue with bond0 interfaces starting properly during boot. A workaround for this issue is to add the following to:

```
 $ echo "ifup bond0" >> /etc/rc.d/rc.local
 $ chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

This will guarantee that the `bond0` interface is properly brought up during boots.

#### References

- [How to setup LACP bonding interface on CentOS 7](https://www.snel.com/support/setup-lacp-bonding-interface-centos-7/)
- [LACP bonding and Linux configuration](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/lacp-bonding-and-linux-configuration/)
- [Linux Basics: Create Network Bonding On CentOS 7/6.5](https://www.unixmen.com/linux-basics-create-network-bonding-on-centos-76-5/)

Comment: Hmmm....did not even notice in mobile you were the one writing the question. I have been playing with vagrant for a while, have to come back at it. What is the host, Mac?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - yeah, did this on a Macbook.

Comment: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)" ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - good point, added a note about this to A'er.